# Java Paint Eraser

Tags: java, swing

I wan to add an eraser into the program but i dun know how to type the code for eraser inside the mouseDragged part.. can anyone help?? thx i am still quite new to java program yet~

//dummypost Can somebody help me understand what exactly is causing the problem. Since I am unable to guess what's happening,I think I have not understood the concept of bridge method properly. It would be helpful if someone can explain a little bit about bridge methods too.//dummypost

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.event.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class DrawingArea extends JPanel
{
private ArrayList<Drawing> drawing = new ArrayList<Drawing>();
private Point startPoint = null;
private Point endPoint = null;
private static int eraser = 0;rivate ArrayList<Drawing> drawing = new ArrayList<Drawing>();
private Point startPoint = null;
private Point endPoint = null;
private static int eraser = 0;

private Color fgColor = Color.BLACK;
private Color bgColor = Color.WHITE;

public DrawingArea()
{
    MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
    addMouseListener(ml);
    addMouseMotionListener(ml);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(bgColor);

        //Custom code to paint all the graphics from the List
    for (DrawingArea.Drawing drw : drawing) 
    {
        g.setColor(drw.getFGColor());
        Point startPoint = drw.getStartPoint();
        Point endPoint = drw.getEndPoint();
        g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    }
        //Paint the graphics as the mouse is being dragged
    g.setColor(fgColor);

    if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null && eraser == 0) 
    {
        g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    }

    if(startPoint != null && endPoint != null && eraser == 1)
    {
        g.clearRect(startPoint.x, startPoint.y,40,40);
    }

}

public void eraser()
{
    eraser = 1;
}


public void clear()
{
    drawing.clear();
    repaint();
}

public void setFGColor(Color fgColor)
{
    this.fgColor = fgColor;
}

public void setBGColor(Color bgColor)
{
    this.bgColor = bgColor;
}

class MyMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
        endPoint = startPoint;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
    // Repaint only the area affected by the mouse dragging
        endPoint = e.getPoint();

        if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null && eraser ==0) 
        {
            Drawing drw = new Drawing(fgColor, startPoint, endPoint);
            drawing.add(drw);   
        }

        if (startPoint != null && endPoint != null && eraser ==1) 
        {

        }
        startPoint = endPoint;
        repaint();      
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        eraser = 0;
    }
}

class Drawing
{
    private Color fgColor;
    private Point startPoint;
    private Point endPoint;

    public Drawing(Color fgColor, Point startPoint, Point endPoint)
    {
        this.fgColor = fgColor;
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
    }

    public Color getFGColor()
    {
        return fgColor;
    }

    public void setFGColor(Color fgColor)
    {
        this.fgColor = fgColor;
    }

    public Point getStartPoint()
    {
        return startPoint;
    }

    public Point getEndPoint()
    {
        return endPoint;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want the eraser to do?

Comment: suppose the eraser can erase the line i draw when i drag but i cant

Comment: Normally you don't erase lines as you drag them just call repaint(). The next  call to paintComponent() will clear everything including the old position of the line and then draw the line at the new position.